# Effect of enabling UAC virtualization on Programs such as Visual Studio?

Tags: cpu, performance, visual-studio, uac

One of the reasons as to why I switched from Visual Studio to Rider is performance, it looks like Visual Studio has been optimized to run on multiple CPU cores and Rider is fine with working on a single CPU core. I started Visual Studio to debug some Android program I had and it took more than two minutes to be stable and afterwards it throws ANR forever. I then follow my instincts and open Task Manager and then I find that its the main process of Visual Studio aka `devenv.exe` that is causing the lag. I right click on that and click on View Details and then it switches the tab to Details tab with the process I right clicked on highlighted, and then I see this option called `UAC virtualization`, I assumed its got something to do with letting the program utilize all the cores and it was disabled and then I tried to enable it got some warning and then proceeded and restarted the program, only that on restart it was lighter than the first time. So does this UAC virtualization tool improve performance of a program when enabled? Could it be a performance cheat?

Comment: Something like this would be trivia to test. So, have you?

Comment: It did work, but the hard drive bottlenecked me still